# render dropdown from product dropdown attribute- Magento 2.0.1

Tags: magento2, product, product-attribute

I have created one drop down attribute, I followed [this tutorial](http://www.dckap.com/blog/display-custom-attribute-value-product-viewlist-page-magento-2/) to get selected values from that attribute. I successfully get the result, But I want to render whole drop down.What I do for achieve this?

Comment: Do you want to show all drop down option list ?

Comment: yes, exactly @Arunendra

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Product Detail Page or on Product List Page you can get attribute (color replace with yours) drop down value using following code:

```
<?php 
$attr = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('color')->getOptions(); 
foreach ($attr as $attrColor) {
    echo $attrColor->getValue();
    echo '<br>';
    echo $attrColor->getLabel(); 
}           
?>
```