# Retrieve dropdown attribute value magento2

Tags: magento2, attributes

Hello I have created one dropdown attribute with code "custom_collection"

I want to show it on product listing page under each product so in list.phtml file i added this code

```
$attr_m = $_product->getData('custom_collection');

echo $attr_m;
```

It returns some id but its not showing the attribute value

Comment: may be this link helpful to you http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/110511/render-dropdown-from-product-dropdown-attribute-magento-2-0-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not find anywhere so i tried custom query and it works

```
 $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

 $collection_attr_id = $_product->getData('custom_collection');

 if(!empty($collection_attr_id)):
    $this->_resources = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()
    ->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
    $connection= $this->_resources->getConnection();
    $themeTable = $this->_resources->getTableName('eav_attribute_option_value');
    $sql = "Select value FROM " . $themeTable . " WHERE option_id = " . $collection_attr_id . ";";
    $result = $connection->fetchAll($sql); 
    echo $result[0]['value'];


 endif;
```